# Silverlight 4 Binding to List of List of objects

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, data-binding

someone can suggest how I can do it?

I have a **public static int _index** in App.xaml.cs

I have a    List <  List  <  Person  > >

foreach     List < Person >       I create a new button

-> foreach button, the click.event of it opens a PopUp.

Now I want to bind the Textboxes of the PopUp to the person-propertys

For example:

PopUp  of Button 1 should bound to List[1][_index]

PopUp  of Button 2 should bound to List[2][_index]

AND:

if the _index is changed, the content of the Textboxes should change too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Bind your List to a ListBox and change the ItemTemplate](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data.aspx).

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more context than that to get a helpful answer.  Why won't a listbox work for you?

Comment: I need real buttons.  Every button simulate a sensor, for example change the color oder position. If I click the "sensor", the popUp shows me the data of the sensor.  thanks

Comment: Take another look at ListBox and the ability to modify how each ListBox item is rendered by customizing the ItemTemplate.  Silverlight's ListBox is not like Windows Forms, it's fully customizable.  You can have each list item rendered using a button and have a click event on the button.  The link I posted above has a detailed example of this, give it a read!

Comment: A ListBox with a proper ItemTemplate is what you need. Please read that link because it's one of the most basic and important things in Silverlight/WPF. You won't go far without a solid understanding of this part.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use a Converter for this.